# Keep only one occurrence of substring in a string

Tags: javascript, string, typescript

I'm looking for a function that removes all occurrences of a substring in a string except the first one, so for example

```
function keepFirst(str, substr) { ... }
keepFirst("This $ is some text $.", "$");
```

should return: `This $ is some text .`

I could do it using `split()` and then `for(){}`, but is there a nicer solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This could be the shortest code that is somewhat efficient. It uses [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment).

```
function keepFirst(str, substr) {
  const [
    first,
    ...rest
  ] = str.split(substr);

  return first + (rest.length
    ? substr + rest.join("")
    : "");
}
```

Comment: I don't know how this performs in terms of efficiency, but that's no aspect for me right now and it's super tiny, I really like it. Thanks, I didn't know about this assignment.

Comment: It actually has an issue: An excessive substr is added to the end of the str if the str doesn't cotain the substr.

Comment: starting the function with an `if(!str.includes(substr)) return str;` could solve this. Any better suggestion?

Comment: @tom You could use a ternary operator.

Answer (score 0):

This solution finds the index of the first occurence of `rep` and removes all of the `rep`s after it.

```js
console.log(keepFirst("This $ is some text $$ with $ signs.", "$"));
function keepFirst(str, rep) {
  var fInd = str.indexOf(rep);
  var first = str.substring(0, fInd + rep.length);
  var rest = str.substring(fInd + rep.length);
  return first + rest.replace(
    new RegExp(rep.replace(/[.*+?^${}()|[\]\\]/g, "\\$&"), 'g'), 
    '');
}
```

Comment: off: Xufox's solution is a little cleaner so I'm gonna use that one but I just wanted to say how awesome you are for putting this together in just a couple of minutes:)